# mysql- can I do INSERT IGNORE with multiple values?

Tags: mysql, insert

I have the following code:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO unsubscribes (email)
VALUES (john@john.com),(kevin@kevin.com),(mike@mike.com),(another@gmail.com)
```

but it repeatedly returns an error...

The error is:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near `'@john.com),(kevin@kevin.com),(mike@mike.com),(another'` at line 1

Any ideas why? It is legal to do insert ignore with multiple values right?

Comment: What error do you get? and what are you trying to do>?

Comment: The error is posted above - I'm trying to post multiple rows to my table, if one of the values already exist i dont want it to post it again... pretty standard

Comment: use unique key for the column not to have duplicate values

Comment: Unique key is not appropriate in this instance as it throws an error when I insert duplicate views.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Put the values inside quotes.

This will work

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO unsubscribes (email) 
VALUES ('john@john.com'),
       ('kevin@kevin.com'),
       ('mike@mike.com'),
       ('another@gmail.com')
```

Note that varchar, text etc values should be inside the quotes.

Comment: Now I get the error - Unknown column 'john@john.com' in 'field list'

Comment: @Ash: try it again by copying from my answer

Comment: Also, because I'm dumb and there might be other dumb people out there also: Don't put the column name in quotes. :S

Answer (score 2):

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO unsubscribes (email) 
VALUES ('john@john.com'),('kevin@kevin.com'),('mike@mike.com'),('another@gmail.com');
```

with the above query i don't find any issues. I think  that you have missed  quotes to enclose string.